# How to fetch all google sheet file list using Android programmatically

Tags: android

I want to display a list of google spreadsheet of user according to user and select a file then parse data in json format to use in Api.

Answer (score 0):

i have use this link for fetch all files from google drive https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/android

and change this line for fetch only spreadsheet data

FileList result = mService.files().list()
                    .setPageSize(20)
                    .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
                    .setQ("mimeType contains 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' ")
                    .execute();